# iOS UIDevice Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on a project and I want to see whether or not the proximity detector is working and what the batteryState is.  Here is my code-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DeviceMonitor {

    init() {
        UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = true

        //Loops for ease of checking
        var timer: Bool = true
        while (timer == true){
            sleep(2)
            BatteryState()
            ProximityState()
        }
    }

    func BatteryState() {
        var batterystate: UIDeviceBatteryState = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState
        println(batterystate)
    }

    func ProximityState() {
        var proximitystate: Bool = UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityState
        println(proximitystate)
    }
}
```

My problem is I just seem to get (Enum value) as my output for BatteryState and the ProximityState is always false (even when held up and screen is black).  Also, how can I compare the BatteryState (it is not a string?  This is probably noobish but I'm just learning Swift...

Answer (score 1):

You should name your functions starting with a lowercase letter. You should do as follow:

```
var batteryState: String {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Unplugged {
        return "Unplugged"
    }
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Charging {
        return "Charging"
    }
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Full {
        return "Full"
    }
    return "Unknown"
}

var batteryCharging: Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Charging
}

var batteryFull: Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Full
}

var unPlugged: Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Unplugged
}
```

> Enable proximity monitoring only when your application needs to be
>   notified of changes to the proximity state. Otherwise, disable
>   proximity monitoring. The default value is false.
>
> Not all iOS devices have proximity sensors. To determine if proximity
>   monitoring is available, attempt to enable it. If the value of the
>   proximityMonitoringEnabled property remains false, proximity
>   monitoring is not available.

```
var proximityState: Bool {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = true

    return UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled ? UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityState : false
}
```

usage:

```
let myBatteryStateDescription = batteryState

let myProximityStateDescription = proximityState ? "True" : "False" 

if proximityState {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  for some reason, the proximity state still stays at false tho...

Comment: sorry for the late reply I you must enable it before checking it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/proximityMonitoringEnabled